# Parsing and Processing Text Files With Pandas. Code Needs to Run in Parallel

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, parallel-processing, hdf5

I have 2000 text files. I want to parse and process them. The output will be a pandas dataframe and I want to save it as a hdf5 file.

Currently I use the parallelpython package (pp) and process a few files per thread and save the output. Once all the data has been parsed and processed I load the files and concatenate them and save the output as one large hdf5 file. Is there a more efficient or pythonic way of doing this?

Rough sketch of current process.

```
def parse_and_process(list_of_file_names):
    ''' take list of file names, parse and process them, save output to hdf5
    '''
    files = load_files(list_of_file_names)
    data_frame = make_data_frame(files)
    processed_data_frame = process_df(data_frame)
    processed_data_frame.to_hdf('save_output_here') 


def main():
    files_to_parse = [..]   

    job_server = pp.Server()
    jobs,output = [],[]

    for batch_files in some_generator(files_to_parse):
        jobs.append(parse_and_process(batch_files))
    for job in jobs:
        output.append(job())

    job_server.destroy()
    concatenate_files() # This is slow and single threaded and can take a lot of ram
```

Edit: For clarity the processing of data is very computationally expensive, it uses a lot of both memory and cpu.

Comment: Should this be over at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: can I double post? The question is more specifically how to efficiently do the task of parallel data processing. I included my code to clarify exactly what the task is.

Comment: Are you sure that you're not IO-bound rather than CPU-bound? If the overhead in `parse_and_process` is mainly due to read/write operations then there's not much to be gained from parallelization.